# Sphinx search max_matches error

Tags: search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I want to customize sphinx search in such a way that I could keep as many records as I want in memory.

I am getting the follwing error:

> searchd error (status: 1): per-query max_matches=25000 out of bounds (per-server max_matches=1000)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case I suggest to set `max_matches` to 100000 on the server side.

Even if you need more you can always use `limit N,M` to fetch slice of result set without going out of bounds.

In my experience humans don't go over 10-20 pages in search results, so 100K should be more than enough.